# null value append string in sql-server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query

```
update quotestable set quotestags= quotestags +', Panchatantra' where quotesid=1374
```

This works only if quotestags is not null. If it is null then it doesnot update.
What is the way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a better solution:

```
UPDATE quotestable
SET quotestags = CASE 
        WHEN quotestags IS NULL
            THEN 'Panchatantra'
        ELSE quotestags + ', Panchatantra'
        END
WHERE quotesid = 1374
```

Because you don't want to append those ', ' when quotestags is null.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
update quotestable set quotestags= COALESCE(quotestags, '') +', Panchatantra' where quotesid=1374
```

This replaces the null value with an empty string to concatenate.

By the way, if `quotestags` is null, the update is still executed, but `null + [value] = null`, so the effect is identical to the situation before update.

Comment: I would prefer [`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) for this case but [`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) also works.

Comment: @Richard, just out of interest, why would you prefer `isnull`? I always prefer `coalesce` because it is ANSI, hence more portable.

Comment: Habit mostly, plus IMHO it is more clearly named (ANSI has never been an issue on the systems I've worked on: ability to port was never a requirement).